# Google Chrome Stripping nonce values from script tags

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, content-security-policy, nonce

I'm trying to add nonce values to my inline scripts to satisfy a stricter CSP. However, I am running into a weird issue where chrome is stripping the value from nonce attributes. When I curl the page, nonce values are present. This is causing the script not to be executed as it now fails the CSP test. I thought this may be due to a rogue extension, but it fails on a perfectly clean version of chrome. (Version 73.0.3683.103 on OSX) The value for the nonce is a random 256 bit base encoded string, so it should satisfy all requirements for the nonce.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

What’s described in the question is actually expected behavior — required per the HTML spec:

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#nonce-attributes:attr-nonce

> Elements that have a nonce content attribute ensure that the crytographic nonce is only exposed to script (and not to side-channels like CSS attribute selectors) by extracting the value from the content attribute, moving it into an internal slot named `[[CryptographicNonce]]`

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/#nonce-attributes:dom-noncedelement-nonce

> …the setter for the `nonce` IDL attribute does not update the corresponding content attribute. This, as well as the below setting of the `nonce` content attribute to the empty string when an element becomes browsing-context connected, is meant to prevent exfiltration of the nonce value through mechanisms that can easily read content attributes, such as selectors.

This behavior was added in an update to the spec at https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/2373 (*Hide `nonce` content attribute values*); see https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2369.

To be clear: the behavior the spec requires is, if the markup source you serve over the wire has:

```html
<script nonce=DhcnhD3khTMePgXw>...</script>
```

…then if you open browser devtools and use the DOM inspector, what you’ll see instead is this:

```html
<script nonce>...</script>
```

That is, the DOM inspector will show no value for the `nonce` attribute on that `script` element.

More accurately: you’ll see no value for the `nonce` attribute on that `script` if the doc is served with a `Content-Security-Policy` header, and the browser is applying the policy in that header.

If you *don’t* serve the doc with a `Content-Security-Policy` header, or browsers don’t apply the policy from it, you’ll see `nonce=DhcnhD3khTMePgXw` for the `script` element in the inspector.

So the lack of a value for that `nonce` attribute in the DOM inspector actually indicates that things are working as expected. That is, it indicates the browser is checking the value for a match against any `nonce-*` source expressions in the `Content-Security-Policy` header.

The way it works inside browsers is: browsers move the `nonce` attribute’s value to an “internal slot” for the browser’s own use. So it stays available to the browser, but hidden from the DOM.

---

https://wpt.fyi/results/content-security-policy/nonce-hiding shows that all current browser engines now conform to the spec on this.

Comment: Mike, thank you for taking the time to clarify what the spec's behavior is. (and for your work with w3c) Perhaps you could use your position to lobby browser vendors  to provide some feedback to the developer that things are working as intended. I think a green checkmark next to the nonce or some other visual marker would have helped indicate that things were working as intended. I understand the rationale behind why it was designed this way, but since no other browser API behaves like this I think it would help in avoiding further confusion when testing different browsers.

Comment: Excellent clarification and exactly what I came to find out, but @tomciopp while it explains why the nonce is missing in the source code, did you manage to work out the CSP issue? Sorry if this is happened too long ago, likely isn't an issue anymore anyway.