# Nonce for PayPal Smart Button inline script

Tags: security, paypal, nonce

I created a nonce with PHP for my PayPal Smart Button inline script to comply with CSP. But the problem I have is that it is exposed and can be seen in the developer tools in Chrome.
On PayPal web site it says to use `data-csp-nonce` attribute and this seems to be the problem as, even though the CSP doesn't complain about the script, it is exposed.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/troubleshoot/support/

If I just use `nonce` attribute the random number is not exposed (which is the expected behavior) but I get an error in the console saying that the inline script does not comply with the CSP. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal and intended for nonces to be exposed within the page and within headers.  The next page load will have a new nonce, so knowing the old nonce is useless.

Comment: That's what I thought initially because every http request creates a new nonce, but then I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55673767/12208549 .