# Nonce is always empty when using spatie/laravel-csp with Laravel and vite.js

Tags: php, reactjs, vite, content-security-policy, laravel-9

I'm facing an issue that the "nonce" value is always empty when using spatie/laravel-csp (v2.8.2) with vite and laravel framework (9.44). I followed the instructions on github page. Here is my configuration:

app/http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            ...
            \Spatie\Csp\AddCspHeaders::class
        ],
```

config/csp.php

```
'nonce_generator' => App\Support\LaravelViteNonceGenerator::class,
```

The used policy uses the nonce directive from basic policy by spatie.

LaravelViteNonceGenerator.php

```
namespace App\Support;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Vite;
use Spatie\Csp\Nonce\NonceGenerator;

class LaravelViteNonceGenerator implements NonceGenerator
{
    public function generate(): string
    {
        return Vite::useCspNonce();
    }
}
```

app.blade.php in my head

```
    @viteReactRefresh
    @vite('resources/js/app.jsx')
```

When I use `@nonce` directive, the nonce has the same random string value like shown in Content-Security-Policy header on my page but the script tag does not get it as attribute.

Some further information:
vite: 3.2.4
@vitejs/plugin-react: 2.2.0
laravel-vite-plugin: 0.6.1

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else is looking for this, I found a solution. The missing key is the `csp_nonce()` directive. So I created a meta tag with `csp_nonce()` directive like this:

```
<meta property="csp-nonce" content="{{ csp_nonce() }}">
```

After that, my vite-injected JS and CSS files got the nonce property and the browser did not block the content any more.

Comment: Where did you get the csp_nonc() fuction from ?

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 It is defined in vendor\spatie\laravel-csp\src\helpers.php

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the nonce attribute is stripped from the script element in Google Chrome. See [Google Chrome Stripping nonce values from script tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670985/google-chrome-stripping-nonce-values-from-script-tags) for a more thorough answer.